# Not able to cache HttpResponse using cachingHttpClient in java?

Tags: java, caching, httpresponse

I'm trying to cache HTTP responses using cachingHttpClient, but in vain.
This is the demo which I put together by refering to this link, http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/caching.html

```
  public class CacheDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CacheConfig cacheConfig = new CacheConfig();
        cacheConfig.setMaxCacheEntries(1000);
        cacheConfig.setMaxObjectSizeBytes(1024 * 1024);

        HttpClient cachingClient = new CachingHttpClient(new DefaultHttpClient(), cacheConfig);

        HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();

        sendRequest(cachingClient, localContext);
        CacheResponseStatus responseStatus = (CacheResponseStatus) localContext.getAttribute(
                CachingHttpClient.CACHE_RESPONSE_STATUS);
        checkResponse(responseStatus);


        sendRequest(cachingClient, localContext);
        responseStatus = (CacheResponseStatus) localContext.getAttribute(
                CachingHttpClient.CACHE_RESPONSE_STATUS);
        checkResponse(responseStatus);
    }

    static void sendRequest(HttpClient cachingClient, HttpContext localContext) {
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://www.mydomain.com/content/");
        HttpResponse response = null;
        try {
            response = cachingClient.execute(httpget, localContext);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        try {
            EntityUtils.consume(entity);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    static void checkResponse(CacheResponseStatus responseStatus) {
        switch (responseStatus) {
            case CACHE_HIT:
                System.out.println("A response was generated from the cache with no requests "
                        + "sent upstream");
                break;
            case CACHE_MODULE_RESPONSE:
                System.out.println("The response was generated directly by the caching module");
                break;
            case CACHE_MISS:
                System.out.println("The response came from an upstream server");
                break;
            case VALIDATED:
                System.out.println("The response was generated from the cache after validating "
                        + "the entry with the origin server");
                break;
        }
    }

  }
```

Its a simple program, but I'm unable to figure out where am I going wrong. Your help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What do you expect to happen and what actually happens?

Comment: @artbristol I want a cache hit when the same http request is sent second time. If your run this example, both the times cache miss occurs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The GET request with url http://www.mydomain.com/content/ will end up with Http 404 code (Not found). This result can not be most likely cached, so that is why it does not work for you I guess.

**UPDATE:**
There must be certain conditions met in order to serve the response from cache.
You should enable logging of apache http client (e.g. http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/logging.html). Than you can debug what is going on and why there are cache misses for your other URLs. You should probably download also source code of the library and have a look there (http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi).  Especially you will be interested in `org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.CachedResponseSuitabilityChecker` class. This should help you also in your following development with the library.

Btw. http://muvireviews.com/celebrity/full_view/41/Shahrukh-khan return this header:

`Cache-Control:no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0, max-age=0, no-cache, no-store`

and because of the if statement in `CachedResponseSuitabilityChecker`:

```
            if (HeaderConstants.CACHE_CONTROL_NO_CACHE.equals(elt.getName())) {
                log.trace("Response contained NO CACHE directive, cache was not suitable");
                return false;
            }
```

the cache will not be used.

Good luck ;)

Comment: ok, so first I replaced the url with http://www.hellomagazine.com/royalty/201204247845/queen-royal-wedding-kate-middleton/ and it gave me a cache hit. But when replaced with http://www.muvireviews.com/celebrity/full_view/41/Shahrukh-khan, there is a cache miss.

Comment: @HarshalKshatriya Look at the updated answer. I hope it will give you answer to your next question.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'll try and revert back if there are any issues.

Comment: @HarshalKshatriya If the answer helped you or you  find it valuable in some regard, please consider to upvote it. It is than more likely you will get help next time.

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&titles=he&rvprop=content&format=json&rvexpandtemplates=true
 is returning `Cache-control => private, must-revalidate, max-age=0`, any idea how to cache the response? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By default CachingHttpClient assume shared cache thereby it will ignore to store if response header contains "Cache-Control: private" (in your case I think that is what is the case). See @ https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/caching.html (Section# 6.4 Configuration)

Try to turn it off, so as to be able to use in client only mode i.e.

```
CacheConfig cacheConfig = new CacheConfig();
cacheConfig.setMaxCacheEntries(1000);
cacheConfig.setMaxObjectSizeBytes(1024 * 1024);
cacheConfig .setSharedCache(false); // Turn it OFF here
```

This worked for me. Good luck !!!

Comment: Any ideas how to cache `Cache-control => private, must-revalidate, max-age=0`. Thanks.